# "But it is true that..." in Japanese

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

I am trying to translate a sentence from English to Japanese in order to include it in an email, but I can't really find a satisfying equivalent in the target language.

> But it is true that it (the Japanese language) is getting easier over time.

I have:

> でもだんだんやさしくなることは本当です。

Or should I say 「やさしくなっていることは」

I have have also tried:

> でもなるほど日本語がますますやさしくなってきています。

Please let me know if this is wrong, or if there is a better way to say it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 「でもだんだんやさしくなることは本当{ほんとう}です。」

Nice try, but it only sounds 80-85% natural.  (It is 100% grammatical if it is the grammar that matters.)

「本当」: A more natural word choice would be 「事実{じじつ}」.  Using 「本当」 there could make it sound a bit childish.

「なる」: The native speaker's phrase choice would be 「なってきている」 or 「なっている」.

> 「でもなるほど日本語がますますやさしくなってきています。」

Excellent second half (やさしくなってきています).  The use of 「なるほど」 there is not incorrect, but a phrase like 「確{たし}かに」 would be more natural.

How natural 「なるほど」 sounds there would actually depend on the larger context.  With only a single sentence given, it is no easy judgement.  In that sense, 「確かに」 would be a pretty safe choice.